# Куда вставить transition?

Tags: html, css

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2eca7f;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Extra</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Куда вставить transition чтобы псевдоэлементы появлялись плавно?

Comment: `display: block;` не анимируется!

Comment: попробывал с inline, inline-block, flex. тоже самое

Comment: это казалось логичным! `display: ... ` хоть `block`, хоть `flex` ....  не анимируются с `dispaly:none` коим псевдоэлемент является по-умолчанию пока вы его не заявите по наведению или еще как иначе. Так же и любой другой блок с `dispaly:none` на `display: block | inline-block | flex ... ` - не анимируется средствами css. Появление осуществляется с помощью `opacity, visibility, transform, ...` или силами javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `opacity`

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin-left: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.navbar ul li a::after {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2eca7f;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Extra</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```